# Angular6 Jasmine TypeError: expect(...).toBeVisible is not a function

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular6, jasmine-jquery

Setting up jasmine-query-matches in angular6

On angular 5 project it looks at simple as

```
import { } from 'jasmine-jquery/lib/jasmine-jquery';
import { } from 'jasmine-jquery-matchers';
import * as $ from 'jquery';
```

On angular 6 i have tried the following

```
import {} from "jasmine-jquery/lib/jasmine-jquery" ;
import {} from "jasmine-jquery-matchers/dist/jasmine-jquery-matchers" ;
import { } from "karma-jasmine-jquery";
import * as $ from 'jquery';
```

OR

```
import {} from "jasmine-jquery" ;
import {} from "jasmine-jquery-matchers" ;
import { } from "karma-jasmine-jquery";
import * as $ from 'jquery';
```

Usage as follows

```
imagesEL = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.cycle'));
```

and

```
expect(imagesEL).toBeVisible();
```

or

```
expect(imagesEL.nativeElement).toBeVisible();
```

But every thing seems to be giving the same error

> TypeError: expect(...).toBeVisible is not a function

Thanks for helping

[Sample Code : https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-test-tobevisible?file=app/hello.component.spec.ts](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-test-tobevisible?file=app/hello.component.spec.ts)

Comment: @amit-chigadani Tried nativeElement not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to use this as your imports

```
import "jasmine-jquery/lib/jasmine-jquery" ;
import "jasmine-jquery-matchers/dist/jasmine-jquery-matchers" ;
import "karma-jasmine-jquery";
import 'jquery';
```

Please note that jasmine-jquery-matchers does not have a default export

Answer (score 0):

`toBeVisible()` should be applied on `nativeElement`

```
imagesEL = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.cycle'));
expect(imagesEL.nativeElement).toBeVisible();
```