# "TypeError: expect(...).toBeVisible is not a function" Error in Angular 6 karma Tests

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, jasmine-matchers

I installed the jasmine-jquery-matchers library using npm into my Angular 6 app.  Running the tests brings up the following error:

```
ERROR in [at-loader] 
./src/app/landing/components/title/title.component.spec.ts:51:30
    TS2339: Property 'toBeVisible' does not exist on type 'Matchers<any>'.
```

Here is my test spec:

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { TitleComponent } from './title.component';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { UserInfoService } from '../../../shared/services/user-info.service';
import {DebugElement} from "@angular/core";
import {By} from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { matchers } from "jasmine-jquery-matchers/dist/jasmine-jquery-matchers" ;

describe('Title Component', () => {
  let component: TitleComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<TitleComponent>;
  let userInfoService: UserInfoService;
  let el: DebugElement; 
  //const matchers = window['jasmine-jquery-matchers'];

  beforeEach(() => {
    jasmine.addMatchers(matchers);

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [ FormsModule, RouterTestingModule ],
      declarations: [ TitleComponent ],
      providers: [ UserInfoService ]
    });

    fixture         = TestBed.createComponent(TitleComponent);
    component       = fixture.componentInstance;
    userInfoService = TestBed.get(UserInfoService);
  });


  it("should be visible when the user service's isPageTitleEnabled() method returns true", () => {
    el = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('div.tc-title')); 
    spyOn(<any>UserInfoService.prototype, 'isPageTitleEnabled').and.returnValue(true);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(el.nativeElement.children.length).toEqual(1);
    el = el.query(By.css('span.tc-header-title')); 
    expect(el.nativeElement).toBeVisible();
  });
});
```

There are other tests which I did not include because they all work.

Here's the stack trace:

```
TypeError: expect(...).toBeVisible is not a function
            at <Jasmine>
            at UserContext.<anonymous> (webpack:///src/app/landing/components/title/title.component.spec.ts:44 <- config/spec-bundle.js:103558:34)
            at ZoneDelegate../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (webpack:///node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:388 <- config/spec-bundle.js:100764:26)
            at ProxyZoneSpec../node_modules/zone.js/dist/proxy.js.ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (webpack:///node_modules/zone.js/dist/proxy.js:128 <- config/spec-bundle.js:100252:39)
            at ZoneDelegate../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (webpack:///node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:387 <- config/spec-bundle.js:100763:32)
            at Zone../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run (webpack:///node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:138 <- config/spec-bundle.js:100514:43)
            at runInTestZone (webpack:///node_modules/zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch.js:145 <- config/spec-bundle.js:99817:34)
            at UserContext.<anonymous> (webpack:///node_modules/zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch.js:160 <- config/spec-bundle.js:99832:20)
            at <Jasmine>
            at ZoneDelegate../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (webpack:///node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:421 <- config/spec-bundle.js:100797:31)
            at Zone../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (webpack:///node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:188 <- config/spec-bundle.js:100564:47)
            at drainMicroTaskQueue (webpack:///node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:595 <- config/spec-bundle.js:100971:35)
```

Maybe I need to configure something in karma.conf.js?  I did add it as a framework:

```
frameworks: ['jasmine', "jasmine-jquery-matchers"],
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

rob

Comment: Did you try the suggestion here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51463562/angular6-jasmine-typeerror-expect-tobevisible-is-not-a-function

Comment: Yes I did.  The "jasmine-jquery-matchers/dist/jasmine-jquery-matchers" import helped, because the docs did not include the dist subfolder. However, the rest didn't help at all.  JQuery is being loaded.  It's the matchers library that seems to be missing from the final rendered web page.

Comment: I reinstalled all of the karma modules and now I see this error:

ERROR in [at-loader] TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'jasmine-jquery-matchers'.

I think that there needs to be @types for the 'jasmine-jquery-matchers'. library.  However, I can't find any online...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found my solution.  It was quite a journey.

In the jasmine-jquery-matchers library's custom-typings.d.ts, it says:

```
* You can include your type definitions in this file until you create one for the @types
```

It then goes on to say:

```
// support NodeJS modules without type definitions
declare module '*';
```

I noticed that jasmine's index.d.ts file declared the "jest-jquery-matchers", so for fun, I added a declaration for jasmine-jquery-matchers as well.  Low and behold, that worked!

Any one know why that fixed the errors?

Rob